# byte[] 0 to 1 with entry wise operation

Tags: c#

Say there is a byte[], which is

```
byte[] myBytes = new byte[W* H];
```

Then the matrix will be all 0s, like

```
     W
| 0 0 0 ... |
| 0 0 0 ... | H
| . . . ... |
| 0 0 0 ... |
```

What is an elegant way to make the matrix become all 1s, like

```
    W
| 1 1 1 ... |
| 1 1 1 ... | H
| . . . ... |
| 1 1 1 ... |
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not a way in C# to initialize all values of an array with a non-default value. The best you can do is set the values in a loop:

for a one-D array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < W * H; i++)
    myBytes[i] = 1;
```

for a 2-D array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < w; i++)
   for(j = 0; j < H; j++)
         myBytes[i,j] = 1;
```

Comment: `myBytes[i * w + j]` may be? Or even a single `[0, w*h)` loop?

Comment: @hyde No, since you can't update the underlying collection in a `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to initialize an array described at this link:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/initialize-array

It has benchmarks too! The recommended way is to initialize the array with a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < W*H; i++){
    myBytes[i] = 1;
}
```

The more "elegant" method described in the link is:

`myBytes = Enumerable.Repeat((byte)-1, W*H).ToArray();`